# mongodb node.js finding document with multiple Ids present in an Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

I have an array which contains Id of a mongodb collection

```
array = [ '573163a52abda310151e5791',
         '57358e5dbd2f8b960aecfa8c',
         '573163da2abda310151e5792' ]
```

like this, in my nodejs code I want to find the documents of all these Ids. the package I'm using is mongoskin.

according to the docs this is the correct way to find the result, which is giving me what I want. But here instead of direct values I want to use the array, but unable to find out how to do that

```
   db.coll.find({
                _id: {
                    $in: [mongoskin.helper.toObjectID("573163da2abda310151e5792"),
                          mongoskin.helper.toObjectID("57358e5dbd2f8b960aecfa8c"),
                          mongoskin.helper.toObjectID("573163a52abda310151e5791")
                    ]
                }
            }).toArray(function(err, docs) {
                console.log(docs);
                res.send(docs)
            });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know much about mongoskin but may be you can try this...

```
var newArray = oldArray.map(function(ele) {
  return mongoskin.helper.toObjectID(ele);
});
OR
var newArray = oldArray.map(mongoskin.helper.toObjectID(ele));
```

So now you may use newArray in your query

```
db.coll.find({
            _id: {
                $in: newArray
            }
        }).toArray(function(err, docs) {
            console.log(docs);
            res.send(docs)
        });
```

Comment: thanks it worked, but why the result i'm getting not in the same order as specified in the array. Is it possible to get the result in the same order?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is useful to you

```
ObjectID = require('mongoskin').ObjectID;
var array1 = ["5736d1210a39c2547cb9d90e","5736d1380a39c2547cb9d90f]
var array2 = [] 
array1.forEach(function(stringId){
array2.push(new ObjectID(stringId)))
})
```

then use this array2 variable in query

```
db.coll.find({
        _id: {
            $in: array2
        }
    }).toArray(function(err, docs) {
        console.log(docs);
        res.send(docs)
    });
```